# Finding a unitary matrix such that conjugation by that unitary matrix make a set of complex matrices real

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Consider the set $\mathcal{X}_N$ to be the set of $N \times N$ Hermitian matrices whose off-diagonal elements are purely imaginary. Does there exist a unitary $U$ such that matrices of the set $U^*\mathcal{X}_NU$ to be real?

For example, when $N=2$ such a $U$ exists:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & i\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & ib\\-ib&c\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\-i&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} c & b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, what about $N=3$ and higher values of $N$?